# Record a sound and play it back after a user-defined delay?

Tags: audio, audio-recording

I'm looking for any piece of software that would record a sound and play it back after certain delay set by user (e.g. 10 seconds). In other words, I would like to constantly listen - on my headphones - to what's going on near the microphone, but with a certain delay.

Software requirements:

- any price
- any operating system (Windows / Linux / OS X)
- any user interface (command-line / graphical)
- optional feature for saving audio

Comment: do you will need a solution ? below suggestions are not automated regarding auto playback after defined delay period ... actual solution could involve a circular memory buffer which is constantly populated by mic and rendered to audio from say an OpenAL server very doable with some effort

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/)

- Free and open-source
- Windows, macOS and Linux are supported
- Graphical, there might be a CLI way of doing the steps listed below, though
- I couldn't figure out how to play the stream *while* saving it to a file. You might want to ask this as a separate question on SU or in the VLC forums.

Steps:

1. In the menu click 'Media', then 'Open Capture Device':
   [image: Screenshot of the Media menu]
2. - Select 'None' as your video device name and optionally set your audio device name to a specific audio device (e.g. if you have multiple ones).
   - Activate the 'Show more options' checkbox at the bottom of the dialog.
   - Set the caching time to your desired delay.
   - Leave the other options untouched and click 'Play'.

   [image: Capture Device dialog with the settings as described in the text]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Python. Here is an example using `sounddevice`.

Below example records audio from microphone for `#seconds` as per variable `duration` which you can modify as per your requirements.

Same contents are played back using standard audio output (speakers).
This code can be scripted and played in a loop.
More on this over [here](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.4/)

**Working Code**

```
import sounddevice as sd
import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav

fs=44100
duration = 10  # seconds
myrecording = sd.rec(duration * fs, samplerate=fs, channels=2, dtype='float64')
print "Recording Audio for %s seconds" %(duration)
sd.wait()
print "Audio recording complete , Playing recorded Audio"
sd.play(myrecording, fs)
sd.wait()
print "Play Audio Complete"
```

**Output**

```
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
Recording Audio for 10 seconds
Audio recording complete , Playing recorded Audio
Play Audio Complete
>>>
```